# Smallest asymmetric relation such that each $k$ elements are dominated by a common element.

Tags: combinatorics, relations, extremal-combinatorics

How large does a non-empty set $X$ need to be if there exists an asymmetric relation $R \subset X^2$ such that for any $k$ elements $x_1,\dots,x_k$ of $X$ there exists a $x \in X$ such that $(x,x_i) \in R$ for all $i$ from $1$ to $k$?

For the purpose of this question we say that a relation is asymmetric if $(x,y) \in R$ implies $(y,x) \not \in R$.

**Example:** for $k=1$ the answer is $|X| \ge 3$, because the 'rock-paper-scissors' relation does the trick: $X = \{r,p,s\}$ and $R = \{(r,p),(p,s),(s,r)\}$ does the trick, and you can check that it is not possible with $|X| \le 2$. For $k=2$, I believe the answer is $|X| \ge 7$.

**Context:** I followed the `Topics in Combinatorics' lecture series by Tim Gowers on YouTube [1] (which I warmly recommend) and this problem was the second part of a problem on a question sheet [2]. The first part of the question is to prove that for each $k$, there exists a relation $R \subset X^2$ with this property for some $X$. You can solve this part with an averaging argument.

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcLrT263p2w&list=PLOft35kj95aYT2SgFbYwEOavJ7gagmCVZ

[2] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFgVrk1n2zxSF5tcfSe5Fxrva0YVhXEl/view

Comment: That is an unusual definition of antisymmetric, because it rules out $aRa$.

Comment: @almagest: One usually says that such a relation is *asymmetric*.

Comment: Thank you both, I changed "antisymmetric" to "asymmetric".

Comment: Without loss of generality your asymmetric relation is a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)), i.e. has the further properth that $x\ne y$ implies $xRy$ or $yRx$. So "tournament" could be a useful word in searching for literature on this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#Paradoxical_tournaments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(k)$ be the smallest number such that there exists an asymmetric relation $R$ on a set $X$ of size $f(k)$, so that for all $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}\subseteq X$, there will exist $x\in X$ so that $(x,x_i)\in R$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$ (what a mouthful!). One can show that
$$
f(k)\ge 2^{k+1}-1 \, .
$$
Furthermore, this bound is tight for $k=1$ and $k=2$. Erdös himself conjectured that $f(k)=2^{k+1}-1$ for all $k\ge 1$. However, the following paper (1) by Szekeres and Szekeres further shows that
$$
f(k)\ge (k+2)2^{k-1}-1
$$
So $f(3)\ge 19$, and $f(3)\neq 15$. In the same paper, they prove $f(3)\le 19$. Here, the asymmetric relation on $19$ vertices which works is the quadratic residue tournament modulo $19$. That is, $X=\mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$, and $(x,y)\in R$ whenever there exists $k\in \mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$ so that $x\equiv y+k^2\pmod{19}$.

Finally, Erdös showed that there exists a constant $C$ for which
$$
f(k)\le Ck^22^k,\qquad \text{for all }k\ge 1
$$
using a probabilistic argument. These are the best bounds I know on $f(k)$.

> (1) E. Szekeres, and G. Szekeres. “On a Problem of Schütte and Erdös.” The Mathematical Gazette, vol. 49, no. 369, 1965, pp. 290–293. JSTOR, [www.jstor.org/stable/3612854](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612854). Accessed 17 Jan. 2021.

Comment: The linked paper assumes a stronger condition, namely that $(x,y) \in R \iff (y,x) \not\in R$.

Comment: @RobPratt As pointed out by bof, If the stronger condition does not already hold you can add extra pairs to the relation until it does. (this does not break the property we are interested in)

Comment: Thanks for the reference.